# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have problem couse i need find bad urls of pictures its my script:

```
import requests
import csv
import time
with open(nazwa_pliku) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    count=0
    mapa = []
    id = 1
    next(csv_reader)
    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[1] != "":
            ID=row[0]
            NUMBER=row[1]
            PICTURES=row[2].split('|')


            for url in PICTURES:
                url="https://sw67383.mywebshop.io/upload_dir/shop/"+url

                result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
                if result.status_code != 200:

                    print(colored("Brak: ", "red"), url)
                    object = {
                        "PRODUCT_ID": ID,
                        "NUMBER":NUMBER,
                        "PHOTO":url,

                    }
                    count += 1
                    mapa.append(object)
                else:
                    print(colored(str(id)+" Poprawny: ", "green"), url)
                id+=1

    print(colored("Liczba Brakujących zdjęć: ", "yellow")+"{}/{}").format(count,id)
    return mapa
```

For example i get it from csv files and I request urls but some times i have connection error i dont know why. Maybe my internet or server.

and i getting error

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sw67383.mywebshop.io', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /upload_dir/shop/maxtone/MAXTON_4306_4.jpg
> (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object.....

What can i do to avoid this problem

I need to check 3000 urls of pictures. And in future much more.

EDIT:
I change it like

```
   for row in csv_reader:
        if row[1] != "":
            ID=row[0]
            NUMBER=row[1]
            PICTURES=row[2].split('|')


            for url in PICTURES:
                url="https://sw67383.mywebshop.io/upload_dir/shop/"+url


                try:
                    result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
                    if result.status_code != 200:

                        print(colored("Brak: ", "red"), url)
                        object = {
                            "PRODUCT_ID": ID,
                            "NUMBER": NUMBER,
                            "PHOTO": url,

                        }
                        count += 1
                        mapa.append(object)
                    else:
                        print(colored(str(id) + " Poprawny: ", "green"), url)
                    id += 1
                except requests.ConnectionError:
                    print("Problem z połączeniem z adresem: {} ".format(url))
```

And now i know when is "time out" but not good when it will bad link to picture (404) :P so maybe i shoud save this to object too? and manual verify link like its correct url or wrong

Comment: Helping avoiding the problem is hard without information what is actually going wrong. What do you intend to do when this happens for one image? Do you want to retry it, do you want to go to the next image?

Comment: Retry couse sometimes url is correct but its geting timeout. I need only bad links when page response but url is wrong like wrong:  https://sw67383.mywebshop.io/upload_dir/shop/maxtone/MAXTON_9026_4.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok I foud it how I can avoid problem:

```
 for url in PICTURES:
                    url="https://sw67383.mywebshop.io/upload_dir/shop/"+url
                    session = requests.Session()
                    retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
                    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
                    session.mount('http://', adapter)
                    session.mount('https://', adapter)

                    result = session.get(url)
                    if result.status_code != 200:

                        print(colored("Brak: ", "red"), url)
                        object = {
                                "PRODUCT_ID": ID,
                                "NUMBER": NUMBER,
                                "PHOTO": url,
                                "COMMUNICATE":"BRAK"

                            }
                         count += 1
                         mapa.append(object)

                     else:
                          print(colored(str(id) + " Poprawny: ", "green"), url)
                     id += 1
```